# Gitlab runner error "Build failed: exit code 1"

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to build Jekyll blog using gitlab runner (for gitlab pages). I get the following error: ERROR: Build failed: exit code 1. So far, everything worked. Link to project: https://gitlab.com/dash.plus/dashBlog

Answer (score 1):

Just add 
  - apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs
And ofc
  - bundle install

inside gitlab-cl.yaml

```
image: ruby:2.3

test:
  stage: test
  script:
  - gem install jekyll
  - bundle install
  - apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs
  - bundle exec jekyll -d test/
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - test
  except:
  - master

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - gem install jekyll
  - bundle install
  - apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs
  - bundle exec jekyll -d public/
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```